# Installing and using libraries with Intellij and Scala

Tags: python, scala, import, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to use Scala's dispatch library, and I'm coming from a Python background where I can

```
pip install dispatch
```

and then import from there. I'm assuming this isn't the case in Scala. The [dispatch site](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) has a script that downloads dispatch with sbt, but my IDE doesn't recognize the library. How can I access the library from within my project? (I'm using IntelliJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Dispatch jar file you can configure Intellij to use the jar directly by adding it your project:

1. Navigate to File->Project Structure->Libraries
2. Press the `+` button
3. Choose `Java`
4. Navigate to the jar file
5. Press Ok when it asks to add the jar to your module

This is a quick way to get your project running with Dispatch but it's a short term solution as it doesn't help you to build your project from the command line.  You'll need to be able to script your build to use your project with continuous integration tools, etc.

Ultimately you'll want to use a build tool like [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).  Intellij has support for all of these and can automatically synchronize its internal project structure with the build tools' configuration.  Here are links to the Intellij support for each of the tools I mentioned:

- SBT:
  http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/
- Maven: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-2.html
- Gradle: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gradle-2.html

Answer (score 8):

The JVM community doesn't really have that concept of "installing" libraries. You declare them in a build tool (for Scala, the standard is SBT) which downloads them as needed. SBT uses [Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy), which keeps a local cache of downloaded dependencies in `~/.ivy2/cache`, just in case you're curious where the downloads are kept.

Create a file called `build.sbt` that contains this line:

`libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"`

Your IDE setup is then based on your build configuration. There are two approaches for this:

- Use a plugin for the build tool that can configure your IDE. I believe this is still the strategy people use to create Eclipse projects from Maven configurations. The best SBT plugin for IntelliJ is [gen-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea). I recommend this approach for IntelliJ 12.
- Use a plugin for the IDE that can comprehend the build configuration. As of IntelliJ 13, the Scala plugin supports SBT reasonably well. Install the Scala plugin, "open" the `build.sbt` file as if it were an IntelliJ project, and you'll get a new project based on that build configuration.

Answer (score 4):

In the Scala world SBT is the stock build tool and it provides the ability to retrieve dependencies from Maven or Ivy2 repositories. So while you have to find the dependency you need somehow, once you do the process of incorporating it into your project is just as simple as the Python construct you illustrate.

As for finding dependencies, most Scala projects will include the SBT dependency you need some place on their project Web site. In other cases you can use one of the public Maven search services. I use both [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) and [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/). The former includes SBT dependency declarations for all its artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler, you can clone my project [skeleton](http://github.com/fractal/skeleton), and add this SBT dependency as a libraryDependency:

"net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"

reload the project, and you are ready to go. It supports workflows using sbt, intellij or eclipse, all managed by SBT.